# Responsive navigation bar gets hide behind the image, image is not going down so that navigation bar gets its position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohYg5.png)
This is the html code of navigation bar.

```
<div class="fullwidth">

<div class="mainheader">
<img src="/thewebsitepoint/img/menu.png" alt="responsive-menu"/>
<form class="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
</form>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourwork.php">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the css section of navigation bar

```
.mainheader{              /*mainheader*/
width: 90%;
height:60px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.mainheader img {        /*responsive-menu-image*/
display:none;

}
```

This is the navigation bar section. On full width it is doing good, but when it goes responsive main slider image is not going down.

```
nav ul {                 /*navbar starts*/
list-style: none;
float: right;
height: 60px;
}

nav li {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: auto;
height: 60px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
color: silver;
display: block;
line-height: 62px;
padding: 0px 25px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
color: white;
background: #1abc9c;
}


.fullwidth {                /*full width for navigation-bar*/
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: black;
border-top: 5px solid #1abc9c;
border-bottom: 3px solid silver;
clear:both;
position: relative;
}
```

Responsive Css section of navigation bar.
    /*----------Responsive 816---------*/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 816px) {
.mainheader .search{         /*Navigation Bar = None*/
display: none;
}
nav ul {
width: 100%;
clear: both;
position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
width: 100%;
clear: both;
position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}


.mainheader img{                        /*Responsive Menu image*/
float:right;
display:block;
margin-top: 12px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I checked your code and I don't see any image to notice the problem you have.

Comment: I have added a image try to check it now. Thanks

Comment: Try using `z-index`.